# Custom rules for Jackson de-serialization

Tags: java, rest, jackson

I have two microservices (both on Java). First is a REST API, let`s say it has class Person as below:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    PersonDetails details;
}
```

And class PersonDetails is:

```
class PersonDetails {
    Integer age;
    Integer height;
    Integer weight;
}
```

The second microservice is receiving Person objects from REST API (using Spring RestTemplate and Jackson). The problem is class Person in the second microservice is a bit different:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    Integer height;
    Integer weight;
}
```

So it has no PersonDetails, but holds the same fields of age, height and weight.
After de-serialization these additional fields are null.
What is the best way to tell Jackson how to de-serialize this class properly?

Comment: if my answer helped you, would you accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

let convert your objects to json :
Person in first MS :

```
{
    "name":"name",
    "details" : {
        "age":15,
        "height":15,
        "weight":15
    }
}
```

Person in second MS :

```
{
    "name":"name",
    "age":15,
    "height":15,
    "weight":15
}
```

for jackson binding there is 2 ways : using the annotation @JsonProperty or you can use DTO design pattern by adding a DTO in one of the MS.

for example you can create an object with mapper as below :

1. create a class DTO on the first MS :

   public class PersonDTO {

   ```
   String name;
   Integer age;
   Integer height;
   Integer weight;

   // getter and Setter
   ```

   }
2. create a mapper :

class PersonMapper {

```
PersonDTO toPersonDto(Person person){
    return new PersonDTO().setWeight(person.getWeight()).setHeight(person.getHeight()).setAge(person.getAge()).setName(person.getName());
}
```

}

3. in the controller you will get a DTO in the input

   @PostMapping
   public void postTest(@RequestBody Person person){
   personMapper.toPersonDto(person)
   }

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I want to do it without additional classes (because classes in my real project are much more complicated and DTO will be very big as well). Is it possible to do the same just using @JsonProperty?